# How to solve the inverse function of a sum with more than one $x$

Tags: analysis, functions, inverse-function

So I know how to find the inverse by switching $x$ with $y$ and solving for $y$ but I'm not sure what to do when the function has a sum of variables, for example:

$$f(x)= 2\ln(x+1)+xe^x−2x^2+1$$
$$f(x)=3\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)−x^3e^{(x−1)}−2x$$

Do I find separate inverses and then add them again or am I just worse than I thought at this? I can't solve for $y$ and get a simple $y=\cdots$ or can I?

Also I found there's a way to not do this when the question asks for a specific point like $f^{-1}(2)$ but most of my questions ask for the derivative of the inverse like $(f^{-1})'(2)$ is there a simpler way to solve this too?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on your post and so, to help you with your question I have to write down a solution. But what I am writing is more of a **hint**.

You can apply [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20differential%20calculus,non%2Dzero%20at%20the%20point.). That is, whenever your function satisfies the assumptions of this theorem, you can find $(f^{-1})'(y)$ using the following formula:
$$
\left(f^{-1}\right)^{\prime}(y)=\frac{1}{f^{\prime}(x)}=\frac{1}{f^{\prime}\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)}
$$
Hope this helps and answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for solving the inverse function. Solving an equation is a different mathematical problem because the [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) are needed.

You cannot find the inverse by adding the inverses of the members of a sum.

An [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) exists only if the function is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection). The inverse function of a [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) is the composition of the inverse functions of the members of the composition in opposite order.

But your functions are not in this form.

Your defining equations for the inverse function
$$2\ln(x+1)+xe^x−2x^2+1=y$$
$$3\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)−x^3e^{(x−1)}−2x=y$$
are polynomial equations in dependence of more than one algebraically monomials ($\ln(x+1),x,e^x$) and ($\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x),x,e^{(x−1)}$) respectively. We therefore don't know how to solve the equation for $x$ by rearranging it by only [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).

The inverses of your elementary functions are not elementary functions.

Sometimes an equation can become simpler for some given numbers $y$ (e.g. your $f^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(2)$), but that seems not the case with your functions.

In the formula of the Inverse function rule you cites, you don't know your $(f^{−1})'$. Fundamentally, this equation cannot be used for inverting functions.